# Libre Calc - Instantiate a class from outside the current library

Tags: class, instance, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am trying to instantiate a class. Within my library `ClassLib`, it is working ok. But if I try to create an instance of it outside of this library ie. Standard lib. It produces the error.

```
Object not accessible.
Invalid object reference.
```

I am using operating system Windows 10. Libre Calc 7.4.7.2.

```vb
REM TestClass ------------------------------------------------------------

Option Compatible
Option ClassModule

sub Main
end sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub ' Constructor
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub ' Destructor

sub testing( s as string )
        msgbox(s)
end sub


REM  Module1 ( ClassLib ) ---------------------------------------------

Sub Main
End Sub

sub test1

        Dim a As Object
        set a = New TestClass
        a.testing(" From Module1 in the ClassLib")

end sub


REM  Test_classInstance -  module in the Standard library ( document ) ------------------

Sub Main
End Sub

sub Test_class_problem 

' this works 

        test1

' Produces the Error - ( See Image link below )

        'Dim b As Object
        'Set b = New ClassLib.TestClass  

' this is produces the same error

        Dim a As Object
        Globalscope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("ClassLib")
        set a = New TestClass
        a.testing("From 'Test_classInstance' in the Standard lib")

end sub
```

[Image showing the Error Message and libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXsE8.png)

Comment: Good example. I had to put the code containing `set a = New TestClass` inside a subroutine to get it to work, so that may have been helpful to show.

Comment: Please take some time to improve the question. In your most recent edit, there is no longer any text, only code, and it no longer shows the new error. Also, the code is not indented or spaced properly. Look at my previous edit. Also, please mention your operating system and version of LibreOffice, in case that is the reason why it worked for me but not for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to clarify fully this time

Comment: Okay, I found a solution that works for that setup. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the `ClassLib.` qualifier, load the library (if it hasn't been loaded yet — apparently for example, editing the module will also load it).

```
Sub TestTheClass
    Dim a As Object
    Globalscope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("ClassLib")
    set a = New TestClass
    a.testing("From Module 'VBASupp' in the Standard lib")
End Sub
```

[image: successful message box]

**EDIT**:

If you want to instantiate the class from a module in a document, then it looks like that way won't work. Instead, we can follow the approach that Access2Base takes, which is to create a subroutine in that library that returns a new instance of the class.

To do this in your example, create a new module `ClassLib.App` with the following code:

```vb
Function NewTestClass
    NewTestClass = New TestClass
End Function
```

Now, to create a new object from a subroutine in a document, do this:

```vb
Globalscope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("ClassLib")
Set a = NewTestClass
a.testing("From 'Test_classInstance' embedded in a document")
```

Comment: Thank  you .... I have modified my question to reflect your suggestions and I am still getting the same result